# Moving Camera Cable Management

Tags: live-recording, cable, broadcast

I am building a production studio, and in the plans have a track that curves around a bend. I have 2 SDI lines that are attached to it, and power that goes to the camera. I want a way for the cables to stay neat and out of the way. If the track was straight, I would use something like a nylon drag chain, but since it is curved, I am posting this.

Any thoughts? There is always the option of putting it into some TechFlex and let it drag around, but that is less than ideal.

Any thoughts, suggestions and recommendations would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Cable trolley, attached to the ceiling.